# List recent records(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, record

I would like to create a model to list recent 5 appointments from appointment table(date,description,status fields).I have Patient and Appointment tables.Here is the code but I think some part missings

```
public ActionResult Recent(Models.AppModel User)
        {
             if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
            {
                using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {
                    var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email ==(String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                    var list = (from m in db.Appointments
                                where m.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo && m.Date<Current.Date
                                select m.ToList());
                               }}

        return View();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Current` is `DateTime.Now` ?

Your filtering (`m.Date<Current.Date`) will select all items whose date is before this point in time. Not just recent items, but **any** item with a past date.

The question is, what is your criterium for 'recent'?

'recent' = The last 7 days

```
DateTime Current = DateTime.Now;
DateTime Past = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

... m.Date < Current && m.Date > Past ...
```

'recent' = The last 20 items (regardless of how old they are)

```
DateTime Current = DateTime.Now;

db.Appointments.Where(m => m.Date < Current.Date)
               .OrderByDescending(x => m.Date)
               .Take(20)
               .ToList();
```

If you have another criterium for what a 'recent' appointment is, please elaborate :)

Comment: thanks for answer so here is my controller but what should return back.and Which method I should use in cshtml file to show the list?public ActionResult Recent(Models.AppModel User)
        {
            if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
            {
                using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {

                    DateTime Current = DateTime.Now;

                    db.Appointments.Where(m => m.Date < Current.Date)
                   .OrderByDescending(x => m.Date)
                   .Take(20)
                   .ToList();} } }

Comment: Copy/pasting in the comments isn't the most readable of options. Also, if you have a second issue with how to handle queries data, that should be a question of it own. So I'd suggest making a new question inregards to populating MVC views with data.